# Issue tracking system with issue hierarchy

Tags: bug-tracking, issue-tracking

Is there a issue tracking system with hierarchy for tasks?

It's pretty obvious taht new-feature-request can be split into more parts (UI change, Bac office-change).

Also bug-solving can be split into multyple tasks.

Is there any tracking system that supports that?

**Edit:**
Any free system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the current issue tracking systems do.

Off the top of my head, Bugzilla, FogBugz, Trac, and Jira all do.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Redmine.
It provides more out from the box than Trac. Trac must be used with various plugins to achieve the similar.
You can read the following for feedbacks:

[Trac wiki page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/RedMine)

> RedMine is the latest incarnation of the Trac clones...
>   Multi-project support...
>   Ticket dependencies!

[Redmine vs Trac](http://www.wamped.org/post/4105652822/choosing-an-issue-tracker-trac-vs-mantis-vs-jira-vs)

> Even if this is a great plugin for trac, - after 6 weeks of using it - I'd still opt for redmine.

[TrackStudio report](http://www.trackstudio.com/comparison-redmine.html)

> So, we think that Redmine can be a very good choice for small teams, but for large scale projects it can be a Herculean task to set things right without commercial task management systems."

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manage a complex hierarchy, I recommend Project Kaiser - it has a good support for hierarchical subprojects and subissues.